# Collatz Conjecture/shared memory C program

Tags: c, shared-memory, collatz

I am a very new programmer trying to understand this C program and get it to run. Currently, it compiles and runs but does absolutely nothing. Last night it was partially working, I was getting numbers but not the correct numbers. We were given a template that had everything (theoretically) except the Collatz section. I've looked over and over it and cannot see anything I've changed since last night. Can anyone help?

Edit: The Collatz conjecture says using this algorithm n = (n/2) if n is even; n = (3*n+1) if n is odd, continually applied, all positive integers will eventually reach 1. I did the same program without shared memory and it worked as written.
Thanks so much!!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define MAX_SEQUENCE 30

typedef struct {
    int size;
    char partial;
    long num[MAX_SEQUENCE];
} shared_data;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* name of the shared memory segment */
    const char *name = "kmm27920";

    /* shared memory file descriptor */
    int shm_fd;
    int i, n;

    /* a pointer to the shared memory segment */
    shared_data* shared_memory;

    int pid;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: a.out num\n");
        return 1;
    }

    n = atoi(argv[1]);

    /* create a shared memory object */
    shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0666);
    /* configure the size of the shared memory object */
    ftruncate(shm_fd, sizeof(shared_data));

    /* memory map the shared memory object */
    shared_memory = (shared_data *) mmap(0, sizeof(shared_data), PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);

    // create child process

    if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to create child process");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pid > 0) {
        wait(NULL);
        for (i = 0; i < shared_memory->size; i++)
            printf("%d\n", shared_memory->num[i]);
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        // generate the collatz sequence and store the result in the shared memory
        // the first term is n
        
        while (n != 1) {
            if (n % 2 == 0){
                n = n / 2;
                shared_memory->num[i] = n;
                i++;
            }
            else if (n % 2 == 1) {
                n = 3 * n + 1;
                shared_memory->num[i] = n;
                i++;
            }
        }
                
        exit(0);
    }

    /* now remove the shared memory object */
    shm_unlink(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I suggest you spend some time learning to use Git or a similar version control tool. When you run into a problem involving "I cannot see anything I've changed," then Git will quickly help you see what has changed.

Comment: Please describe what the code needs to do. Just saying "Collatz Conjecture" is not sufficient. For example, what does the requirement say about how multi process and shared memory need to be used? Finally, and most importantly, what basic debugging have you done? If the program does "absolutely nothing" then at least add more debugging print statements to see exactly what it is doing. Even better, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: I will see if I can integrate that into the system we are using, thank you. Currently, we have to use the University's Linux server via Putty to do any submissions and so I have been working on it there. It does not have any debugging capabilities. I may have to work elsewhere and transfer it over. Let me see if I can find a debugger to run it through.

Comment: Sorry, The collatz conjecture is this part of the code it should display the starting number do the math as below and display each number until it gets to 1                         
         ``` while(n!=1){
            if (n%2==0){
                n = n/2;
                shared_memory->num[i]=n;
                i++;
            }
            else if(n%2==1){
                n = 3*n+1;
                shared_memory->num[i] = n;
                i++;
            }  ```

Comment: I have had the problem before where the program crashes and leaves the shared memory segment locked and then your program can't create it or delete it.  Try deleting it from the command line (I think the command is `ipcrm`)  Rebooting the computer would also get rid of it.

Comment: I don't think I can reboot as I'm using the University Server through SSH everything is stored there. I will try the ipcrm

Comment: You should just download a Linux distro like Ubuntu to your home PC. It is free of charge and you can spin it up in a VM, or boot it off a USB stick without installing. This will make your work much easier, letting you use debug tools and make changes fast. If you are on Windows 11, you may want to try Linux Subsystem for Windows, though I heard it has some serious issues.

Comment: Bear in mind that "all positive integers" in the range of the input's `int` will need a larger type to operate with: `INT_MAX` is odd, and so you must immediately triple it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is called a "conjecture" is because to this day, no one has been able to prove that it does hold for any integer.

On the other hand, no one has found an integer that does not hit 1 at some point, or more specifically, a loop other than 1, 4, 2.

And many people have tried.

The reason this is important is because it is very likely the cause of failure for your program.

To be more specific, there are 2 reasons it fails:

First, you do not initialize `i` in the child process, the part where this loop is:

```
while(n!=1){
    ...
}
```

This means instead of starting to put results in `shared_memory->num[0]` you put them at an unknown index, which may be outside your array, causing memory corruption.

Second, the loop it self loops until `n == 1` but depending on the input, this can take many more iterations than 30!

If I remember correctly, there is no way to calculate how many iterations a given number will require before reaching 1.

In your shared memory object you only have space for 30 numbers, meaning you must reach 1 in 30 steps or less.

But your program never checks that, so you could start writing to memory out of bounds of your array, which is "undefined behavior".

That means you program can crash, run forever, or print random wrong numbers, etc.

Finally, if by some miracle you do use a number that reaches 1 in less than 30 steps, and your `i` variable somehow starts with value 0, you still never initialize `shared_memory->size` which means your printing loop won't know when to stop, and will most likely print garbage.